# test visual saliency by opencv [ERROR:0@463.189] Can't open archive: '/ObjNessB2W8HSV.wS1.yml.gz'

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to test the area of visual saliency in a photo and i use the objectness method. However, python gives me several same error tips:

```
[ERROR:0@463.189] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp (514) cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open archive: '/ObjNessB2W8HSV.wS1.yml.gz' mode=rb3
```

what does it mean?
the code is following and the last code got problem:

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

saliency = cv2.saliency.ObjectnessBING_create()
# saliency.setTrainingPath(args["model"])

(success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(image)
numDetections = saliencyMap.shape[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectnessBING` tries to load a pretrained model to compute the saliency.
the [models are all here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/4.x/modules/saliency/samples/ObjectnessTrainedModel) so, if you have the src code,  try to set:

```
saliency.setTrainingPath("path/to/ObjectnessTrainedModel")
```

else try to download the model from:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/raw/4.x/modules/saliency/samples/ObjectnessTrainedModel/ObjNessB2W8HSV.wS1.yml.gz

(note the "raw" in the url, else you dl the github html !)

and put it next to your app. gl!

Comment: Even after specifying `setTrainingPath`, when I go to `computeSaliency` it throws `Can't load model: Downloads\ObjNessB2W8HSV.wS1.yml.gz/ObjNessB2W8MAXBGR.wS1 or Downloads\ObjNessB2W8HSV.wS1.yml.gz/ObjNessB2W8MAXBGR.idx`. Any thoughts?

Comment: again, check if it is really yml.gz, not a html error msg (download error or such)